# Python image stacking

Tags: python, numpy, rgb

I have 20 images, and i want to stack them, as in for each pixel location, Image stacking is a process where we take the average over a batch of images. Specifically, we will
create a new image where each pixel at a position (x, y) in the image is the average of all pixels at the same position (x, y) in each of the N images of the batch:

x_stacked, y_stacked = sum from i to N of (x_i, y_i) / N

But i also need to remove regions of white pixel. Any fully-white pixel (a pixel of 255 in all color components) is a noisy pixel, and thus should not be included when calculating the average of a pixel. That is, while iterating over each of the 20 versions of a photo and taking
the average of each pixel, we will skip a pixel if it has the intensity (255, 255, 255). We must also
take care when dividing by N to decrease the value of N for every white pixel for that location (x,
y) (e.g., if 5 of the 20 versions had a fully-white pixel for a location (x, y), then when calculating
the average pixel for that location, we must divide by 15 instead of 20).

this is what i have so far:

```
def denoise(filename):
n = 20
images = []
for i in range(n):
    image = io.imread(filename + str(i) + '.png')
    h, w, _ = image.shape
    image = image.reshape((h * w, 3))
    images.append(image)
finalImage = np.zeros((h * w, 3))
for i in range(len(images[0])):
    pixel = []
    for j in range(n):
        if (images[j][i].all() != 255):
            pixel.append(images[j][i])
    pixel = np.asarray(pixel)
    pixel = pixel.T
    finalImage[i][0] = np.mean(pixel[0])
    finalImage[i][1] = np.mean(pixel[1])
    finalImage[i][2] = np.mean(pixel[2])
finalImage = finalImage.reshape((h, w, 3))
avgImg = Image.fromarray(finalImage.astype('uint8'))
avgImg.show()
```

it works, except for removing the white noise

Answer (score 1):

You may compute the sum all images, compute the total "summed" elements per image,  and divide sum by count at the end:

Define two matrices:

- `img_sum` - Sum of images (excluding the components where all equal 255)
- `img_cnt` - Count components that are not all 255 (named `N` in your post).

The final result equals `img_sum / img_cnt`.

For avoiding division by zero, it is recommended to replace zeros in the denominator before the division.
It is also recommended to set result to 255 where value is 255 in all input images.

Instead of iterating all the pixels, you better use NumPy array operations, like array sum, array division, and logical indexing.

Here is the code (please read the comments):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Generate list of synthetic images (for testing):
images = []
###############################################################################
width, height, n_frames = 640, 480, 20  # 20 images, resolution 640x480

for i in range(n_frames):
    img = np.full((height, width, 3), 60, np.uint8)
    cv2.putText(img, str(i+1), (width//2-100*len(str(i+1)), height//2+100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 10, (255, 255, 255), 20)  # White number
    cv2.rectangle(img, (20, 20), (width-19, height-19), (200, 0, 0), thickness=10)  # Blue rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(img, (100, 100), (width-99, height-99), (0, 200, 0), thickness=8)  # Green rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(img, (10, 10), (30, 30), (255, 255, 255), thickness=6)  # White rectangle (for testing pixels where with 255 in all input images)
    images.append(img)

    #Show image for testing
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(50)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
###############################################################################

img_sum = np.zeros(img.shape)  # Sum of images (excluding intensities equal 255)
img_cnt = np.zeros(img.shape)  # Count intensities that are not 255

# Iterate list of images, and update img_sum and img_cnt
for img in images:
    no_sat = np.any(img < 255, 2)  # Matrix with True where all color components are not saturated (255), and False where all components are 255
    no_sat = np.dstack((no_sat, no_sat, no_sat)) # Duplicate no_sat three times (from single plane to 3 plances)
    img_cnt = img_cnt + no_sat.astype(float)  # Count non-saturated pixels (True is counted as 1.0 and False counted as 0)
    img[np.logical_not(no_sat)] = 0  # Replace 255 values to zero (use logical indexing)
    img_sum = img_sum + img.astype(float)  # Sum images (with 0 where value was 255), cast to float for avoiding overflow.

# Before dividing img_sum by img_cnt, we must verify there are no elements with img_cnt = 0 (avoid division by zero)
nonzeros_img_cnt = np.maximum(img_cnt, 1)  # Use maximum with 1 for replacing all zeros with 1

# Divide sum by count, for computing the average.
avg_img = img_sum / nonzeros_img_cnt

# What about the pixels that equals 255 in all the input images?
# Best solution is setting them to 255 in avg_img
# The elements where all equals 255 are equal zero in img_cnt
# Set avg_img elements to 255 where img_cnt = 0 (use logical indexing):
avg_img[img_cnt == 0] = 255

# Round an cast to uint8
avg_img = np.round(avg_img).astype(np.uint8)

# Show result
cv2.imshow('avg_img', avg_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Example for synthetic input images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

`avg_img` (final result):
[image]

---

### Update:

Reading images using `scikit.io` of [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/) module:

You can read the images using `io.imread` as in your original code.
Remove the line `image = image.reshape((h * w, 3))`, because my code sample is working with 3D arrays.

Here is a code sample that saves the synthetic images into PNG image files using OpenCV, and reads the images using `io.imread` from `skimage`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage import io

# Generate list of synthetic images (for testing):
###############################################################################
width, height, n_frames = 640, 480, 20  # 20 images, resolution 640x480
filename = 'im'

for i in range(n_frames):
    img = np.full((height, width, 3), 60, np.uint8)
    cv2.putText(img, str(i+1), (width//2-100*len(str(i+1)), height//2+100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 10, (255, 255, 255), 20)  # White number
    cv2.rectangle(img, (20, 20), (width-19, height-19), (255, 0, 0), thickness=10)  # Blue rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(img, (100, 100), (width-99, height-99), (0, 255, 0), thickness=8)  # Green rectangle
    cv2.rectangle(img, (10, 10), (30, 30), (255, 255, 255), thickness=6)  # White rectangle (for testing pixels where with 255 in all input images)
    cv2.imwrite(filename + str(i) + '.png', img)  # Write synthetic image to PNG image file
###############################################################################

# Read images into a list 
images = []
for i in range(n_frames):
    image = io.imread(filename + str(i) + '.png')
    images.append(image)


img_sum = np.zeros(image.shape)  # Sum of images (excluding intensities equal 255)
img_cnt = np.zeros(image.shape)  # Count intensities that are not 255

# Iterate list of images, and update img_sum and img_cnt
for img in images:
    no_sat = np.any(img < 255, 2)  # Matrix with True where all color components are not saturated (255), and False where all components are 255
    no_sat = np.dstack((no_sat, no_sat, no_sat)) # Duplicate no_sat three times (from single plane to 3 plances)
    img_cnt = img_cnt + no_sat.astype(float)  # Count non-saturated pixels (True is counted as 1.0 and False counted as 0)
    img[np.logical_not(no_sat)] = 0  # Replace 255 values to zero (use logical indexing)
    img_sum = img_sum + img.astype(float)  # Sum images (with 0 where value was 255), cast to float for avoiding overflow.

# Before dividing img_sum by img_cnt, we must verify there are no elements with img_cnt = 0 (avoid division by zero)
nonzeros_img_cnt = np.maximum(img_cnt, 1)  # Use maximum with 1 for replacing all zeros with 1

# Divide sum by count, for computing the average.
avg_img = img_sum / nonzeros_img_cnt

# What about the pixels that equals 255 in all the input images?
# Best solution is setting them to 255 in avg_img
# The elements where all equals 255 are equal zero in img_cnt
# Set avg_img elements to 255 where img_cnt = 0 (use logical indexing):
avg_img[img_cnt == 0] = 255

# Round an cast to uint8
avg_img = np.round(avg_img).astype(np.uint8)

# Show result
io.imshow(avg_img)
io.show()
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you. I hope the OP understands my answer. I didn't use any of the originally posted code in my answer, which is not so nice.

Comment: Hopefully we are all here to learn and open our minds to new ways of doing things.

Comment: how are you inputing the actual images? i am inputing images using image = io.imread(filename + str(i) + '.png'), where images are actual pictures like this: https://ibb.co/gFcy1L2

Comment: Just remove the line `image = image.reshape((h * w, 3))`. I updated my post. Be careful not to overwrite your own image files. The code creates file named `im0.png`, `im1.png`...